# LINQ across multiple databases

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I've got two tables that need to be joined via LINQ, but they live in different databases. Right now I'm returning the results of one table, then looping through and retrieving the results of the other, which as you can guess isn't terribly efficient. Is there any way to get them into a single LINQ statement? Is there any other way to construct this to avoid the looping? I'm just looking for ideas, in case I'm overlooking something.

Note that I can't alter the databases, i.e. I can't create a view in one that references the other. Something I haven't tried yet is creating views in a third database that references both tables. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Why can't you change the database(s)?

Comment: Third-party. DBA's want to stay away from creating objects there, even if it's a simple view.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You *can* do this, even across servers, as long as you can access one database from the other.  That is, if it's possible to write a SQL statement against *ServerA*.*DatabaseA* that accesses *ServerB*.*DatabaseB*.*schema*.*TableWhatever*, then you can do the same thing in LINQ.

To do it, you'll need to edit the .dbml file by hand.  You can do this in VS 2008 easily like this:  Right-click, choose **Open With...**, and select **XML Editor**.

Look at the **Connection** element, which should be at the top of the file.  What you need to do is provide an explicit database name (and server name, if different) for tables not in the database pointed to by that connection string.

The opening tag for a **Table** element in your .dbml looks like this:

```
<Table Name="dbo.Customers" Member="Customers">
```

What you need to do is, for any table *not* in the connection string's database, change that **Name** attribute to something like one of these:

```
<Table Name="SomeOtherDatabase.dbo.Customers" Member="Customers">
<Table Name="SomeOtherServer.SomeOtherDatabase.dbo.Customers" Member="Customers">
```

If you run into problems, make sure the other database (or server) is really accessible from your original database (or server).  In SQL Server Management Studio, try writing a small SQL statement running against your original database that does something like this:

```
SELECT SomeColumn
FROM OtherServer.OtherDatabase.dbo.SomeTable
```

If *that* doesn't work, make sure you have a user or login with access to both databases with the same password.  It should, of course, be the same as the one used in your .dbml's connection string.

Comment: If there is concern about modifying a generated file, I recommend extracting the generated (C# or VB) class to a file under manual control and making the change in the attributes on that class.

Comment: You can change the source in the O/R-Designer as well. Just open the properties of a table, look for "source", which will contain "dbo.Customers" and can be changed to contain the database name "SomeOtherDatabase.dbo.Customers".
So this is no hack, it's perfectly fine to change the source.

Comment: I was looking through a slew of questions and answers here about this, and everyone kept saying it can't be done.. it can't be done.. it can't be done.. i was getting frustrated, but this answer works great.  Only to prepare it I have to create all the tables in a temporary database to create the model, then go back and fix the table names and point it to the production database.  a bit of effort, but it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 6):

Create a proc/view in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Given your conditions, I don't think you can do this in one Linq statement.  But you can join the results of your L2S queries into a Linq to Objects query.