# What exactly is a database schema?

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-schema

I hope I don't make myself completely ridiculous, but I'll have to admit that the definition `database schema` is not 100% clear to me.

I *thought* it would be some kind of a blueprint for my tables in my database. In terms of entity framework my `DbContext` would be my 'database schema'.

I began to realize that I am wrong reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) article (suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179407/ef-database-design-issues-regarding-cross-database-relations#comment21403824_15179407) question), where multi tenancy can be achieved by **Shared Database, Separate Schemas**.

Can somebody elaborate?

PS: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298739/what-is-the-difference-between-a-schema-and-a-table-and-a-database) question but that doesn't really answer my somewhat n00bish question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general understanding is as was explained in the question you referenced

> schema : database : table :: floor plan : house : room

That is a schema is the blueprint for you database, and in that sense you DBContext + migrations could loosely be considered a database schema.

However there is also a second way the word schema is used in databases, and that is as a partitioned set (tenant) within the database. This is usually used for security.

All tables are defined within a specific schema (for example DBO) and when you query you are actually querying against tables in a specific schema hence

```
SELECT * FROM [database].[schema].[table]
```

To answer your question there are 2 meanings to this, one is the english language meaning of the word, the other is the actual SQL meaning (which is to do with tenancy)

[image]