# Binding SQL LINQ result to datagridview vb.net

Tags: linq, datagridview

I want to create a LINQ to entities query getting data(join) out of two tables and bind the result as datasource to a datagridview.

Unfortunately I seem to stumble upon a syntax issue.

Table 1 : dcpricing.tblpricing
Table 2 : dcpropertydetail.tblpropertydetail

Grid: grdpricing

```
Dim qry = (From propertyobj In dcPropertyDetail.tblproperydetail
                  Join Pricingobj In dcPricing.tblpricing
                  On propertyobj.prop_det_index Equals Pricingobj.prop_id
                  Where (propertyobj.prop_det_Status = 1)
                  Select propertyobj.prop_det_Name,          Pricingobj.prop_rental_double).ToList

grdpricing.datasource = qry
```

The error pops when passing the query and shows:
[COLOR="Red"]The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.[/COLOR]

I appreciate all help!
Stijn

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you *exactly* what the problem is - you've got a query that is trying to span data contexts.  Specifically, your `tblpropertydetail` table comes from the `dcPropertyDetail` data context, and your `tblpricing` table comes from the `dcPricing` context.  This is not allowed in Entity Framework.

Is there some reason you can't have them in the same data context?  If they are in different databases, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610197/ado-net-entity-framework-across-multiple-databases) for a workaround.