# Linq to SQL - Can changes persist over different DataContext instances

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

If I retrieve an object from the database using Linq to SQL in one method using an instance of DataContext, which closes on exit of that method, can I edit the object in a different method and with a different DataContext and have the changes take effect in the database?

i.e. Would something like the below work?

```
public void Foo()
{
  using (var db = new DataContext())
  {
    Bar a = this.GetBar();
    if (a != null)
    {
      a.Property1 = true;
      db.SubmitChanges();
    }
  }
}

private Bar GetBar(string val)
{
  using (var db = new DataContext())
  {
    return db.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Property2 == val); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use two different data contexts in one LINQ request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447415/how-can-i-use-two-different-data-contexts-in-one-linq-request)

Comment: @JordyDieltjens That seems to be across two different databases, whilst I'm asking about the same database, just different instances of DataContext

Answer (score 0):

There should be some kind of [Attach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method

Something like:

```
public void Foo()
{
  using (var db = new DataContext())
  {
    Bar a = this.GetBar();
    if (a != null)
    {
      db.Bars.Attach(a);
      a.Property1 = true;
      db.SubmitChanges();
    }
  }
}
```