# Using a function with LINQ across multiple databases

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have my current project set up so that I can query across two databases on two different servers using the same LINQ to SQL data context (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352949/linq-across-multiple-databases).)
However, when I'm trying to call a function that is on the database that I manually edited the file for, I am getting errors.
I first noticed that the `Source` field in the Properties was grayed out, so I had to go into the xml of the dmbl file to edit the source. The `Source` now shows up correctly (`DEVSQL01.MyDB.dbo.MyFunction`), but when I try to call the function I get an error saying  `Invalid column name 'DEVSQL01'.`

Does anybody know if what I'm trying to do is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just recreating the function on the second database. If anybody finds another way to do it I'd love to hear it.