# LINQ to SQL over multiple databases - Failover Partner?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have an ASP.NET site using LINQ to SQL set up with multiple databases (by changing the Source for the tables on the other/"secondary" server). As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352949/linq-across-multiple-databases).

How do I set up a Failover Partner for this? I have it set up in the connection string, but I had to hardcode the Source with the server name, so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method I could find/come up with was to create two [LINQ External Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386907%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). On startup, I check to see if the main server is running using the main Mapping. If it's not, I set my connections to use the second LINQ mapping that has the FailOver database:

```
var xmlPath = @"C:\myAppFailOver.map";
System.Data.Linq.Mapping.XmlMappingSource linqMapping = System.Data.Linq.Mapping.XmlMappingSource.FromReader(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(xmlPath));
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext(connString, linqMapping))
{
    //code
}
```