# LINQ Join Tables from Different Database or DataContext

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

```cs
var possibleTPMs = (from ui in db1.Users
                    from org in db2.Orgs.Where(o => o.OrgId == ui.OrgId && !o.DeletedFlag).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where !ui.DeletedFlag && ui.ActiveFlag && ui.OrgId == 1 && ui.UserId != 1
                    select new { ui.UserId, ui.LastName, ui.FirstName }).ToList();
```

Above is sample LINQ  but having errors, How can I join these two tables that came from two different databases.

Comment: really? so Im screwed :(
Any suggestion? mitigation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ across multiple databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352949/linq-across-multiple-databases)

Answer (score 0):

To join two 'tables' you simply join them with the below syntax. You shouldn't need any complex join using wheres

`var possibleTPMs = (from ui in db1.Users
                               join  org in db2.Orgs on ui.id equals org.id
                                select new { ui.UserId, ui.LastName, ui.FirstName }).ToList();`

Comment: Hi @Villapando if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This doesn't work : 'The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.'