# LINQ to SQL and synonyms (Cross database query)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a problem in that I can't add a synonym to the LINQ to SQL designer in Visual Studio, even though in the properties, it knows that the base object is a stored procedure.

Basically, I need use synonyms in order to not have to use any stored procedures because I have 2 databases in 2 different server locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the procedures directly using the designer. Edit their properties using the Properties Window to point to the synonym instead. Or, edit the DBML file to do that.

Comment: I was just reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352949/linq-across-multiple-databases#answer-353106  But I'm not sure if the queries are `SQL` queries or how you can access to the objects

Comment: I've been doing what the linked answer suggests. I also have found a way to change the database name at runtime by modifying L2S internal data structures using Reflection. Nasty.

Comment: I think that use Stored Proceadures it's the better option, now it's working.